# Crystal Report 11-Chosing a value from a slice of the pie

Tags: highcharts, crystal-reports

Hi I have a pie chart with 8 slices in  crystal report 13, I want to chose the maximum value among the slices so I can use it in a text narrative. Eg The share of the segment xx is the highest by @maxsegshare among all other segment shares.The @maxsegshare should capture the highest value among the slices in the pie chart. I have no idea whether it is possible? If it is could some one throw some light on it.
Cheers.

Comment: Are you calling crystal from vb, or another language, or straight from crystal?

Comment: Calling it straight from Crystal reports

Answer (score 0):

Try to create another query,  with `SELECT MAX(some_field) ...`, then fill a variable to be used in other chart.

Comment: Thanks so much Flavio for your replies.Sorry No joy when I use the maximum function on the summarized field it throws an error saying that this filed cannot be summarized. I should have been clear. The data source is an xls file and the pie chart uses the following definition. On change of summary_.Sector A and show values is sum of summary_.relateddeathclaims. So one of the slice has a value of 24.4% and I want that value in a variable so I can use it in my text narrative.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you need to store all summary values in a array and pick the max of the array and diplay in saperate variable.

When you are summarizing the data.. add the following code.

```
Shared Stringvar Array store;

store:=store+ ToText(Summarized value);
1
```

Now when you display, create a formula and write below code

```
Shared Stringvar Array store;
Maximum(store);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Siva, you directed me to think in a different way. I tried the code  the result throws another set of row of values in my case is all the lines are returning 1, the last  value of the first formula. My summarizing formula is as follows Shared Numbervar Array store;

store:=store+ sum({summary_.relateddeathclaims},{summary_.SECTOR-ID});

1

Comment: Thanks so much Siva, you directed me to think in a different way. I tried the code  the result throws another set of row of values because I display the formula in a group section in my case  the last 4 lines have 44 which is the maximum value,SUmmary formula within a group section.Shared Numbervar Array store;
store:=store+ sum({summary_.relateddeathclaims},{summary_.SECTOR-ID});
calling the max formula in the same group section other wise throws an error 1 the size of the array must be greater than 0.I want to isolate the value. I know I am not doing it right.where am I going wrong?

Comment: don't try to display in the section where you are trying to add in array as it will throw error and if you want to display some value other thatn `1` then in place of `1` write `sum({summary_.relateddeathclaims},{summary_.SECTOR-ID});` and display in different section after completely storing the values in array.

Comment: Thanks again Siva, I followed your instructions exactly, while the result is not what I desire the concept works. In my case I have a feeling the sum with the Sector-ID IF conditions is creating an array for each sector ID and the final Maximum formula picks the last array and not the max among all arrays.My final value was actually a max value of one sector id.Thanks so much for your inputs appreciate that very much.